# Существует ли в русском языке слово «соваешься»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, глаголы

Не мог найти информацию о существовании слова **соваешься**. Откуда оно взялось в русском языке?

Comment: Откуда  **от куда**?

Answer (score 2):

Правильное (литературное) произношение таково:
[сова́ть(ся)](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) — сую́(сь), суёшь(ся) (*суёшься не в свое дело*), суёт(ся), суём(ся), суёте(сь), сую́т(ся); су́й(ся) (*не зная броду, не суйся в воду*), су́йте(сь).

Точно таким же образом, например, спрягается глагол *кова́ться*.

Если скажем, что сло́ва *соваешься* (и его разновидностей) нет в языке, то это, думаю, будет не совсем верно, так как его используют малограмотные люди, вполне возможно — иностранцы, изучающие русский язык, писатели — чтобы передать речь таких персонажей.

Другое дело — "несловарность" и "нелитературность" (наряду с использованием слов "транвай", "кило́метр", "людя́м", "колидор", "тубаретка"...).

> — Не суйся, не суйся! — кричал Петя, хохоча, и хлопал ладонями по теплой сухой земле, испятнанной известковыми звездами домашней птицы.
> — **Не совайся**! — суетливо повторяла Мотя, поглядывая через плечико на красивого мальчика, и морщила худой, остренький нос, пестрый, как у Гаврика.
> Третья картина изображала того же казака и ту же сопку. Теперь из-за нее виднелись гетры удирающего японца. Внизу было написано:
>
> Генерал японский Ноги,
> Батюшки,
> Чуть унес от русских ноги,
> Матушки!
>
> — **Не совайся, не совайся**! — заливалась Мотя, прижимаясь доверчиво к Пете. — Правда, пускай тоже **не совается**!
> (Валентин Катаев. Белеет парус одинокий)

*— Марийка, ты возле начальства **соваешься**, не сообщали, может, нас сглазили?* (Алла Хемлин. Заморок; в значении "слоняться, бродить без дела").

Answer (score 0):

Такое слово в русском языке не используется. *"Соваться"* во втором лице настоящего времени — *"суёшься"*.

Comment: @oleedd вы настолько невнимательны, что даже не можете заметить выделенную рамкой ремарку: "Внимание, этот разбор произведён алгоритмически и может содержать ошибки". Подобные сайты работают автоматически и могут генерировать несуществующие в русском языке варианты как не фиг делать. Разумеется, никаким авторитетом они не обладают. Как и те, кто ими пользуется.

Comment: Да хорошо, заметил и без вас, даже исправить не дали!

Comment: Используется, слышал. Сленговый вариант.

Comment: @oleedd найдите авторитетный словарь, где это слово помечено как сленговое. То, что какие-то неграмотные люди его используют, не означает, что это допустимо. Пора бы вам это понять.

Comment: Да пофиг на словарь, факт в том, что люди иногда его используют. Такие формы (противоречащие норме) в словари не добавляют. Ясно, что это не норма, но также ясно, что даже ненормативные вещи используются. Просто вы говорите "не используется", придрался к этому.

Comment: [Вот](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=не+совайся), при нормативном "не суйся". В списке Паустовский.

Comment: @oleedd какой же вы глупенький...

Comment: Ну не глупее вас, вы-то вообще глупец.

Comment: @oleedd ну да, да... Когда в нацкорпусе 6 вхождений, последнее в 1956 году и во всех случаях авторами изображается речь неграмотного персонажа — это аргумент "умного" в пользу "существования" слова как "сленгового", ага...

Comment: Нет, в пользу просто существования. Оно молодёжное, поэтому ближе к сленгу.

Comment: @oleedd какой же вы глупенький...(3) 1956 год последнего зафиксированного Нацкорпусом упоминания — молодёжное... Идите к своим бомжам у подъезда, послушайте, какие ещё глубины русского языка они вам откроют.

Comment: Какой же вы глупец (10). А в 1956 году молодёжи не было, да? А вы не переводите стрелки, это вы проболтались о бомжах.

Comment: А на большее мозгов не хватает?

Comment: @oleedd учитывая, что я за 22 дня заработал 1000 баллов, а вы за два с половиной года едва наскребли 8000, любой сделает вывод, у кого как с мозгами. Отсюда, видать, и ваша лютая зависть, заставляющая вас беспрестанно кидать под мои ответы безаргументные комментарии, вместо того чтобы самому разродиться ответом. Скорее всего, вы понимаете, что, поскольку с аргументами вам ответить нечего, ваш ответ заминусуют и удалят, потому и пытаетесь хоть какую-то выдать своему эго компенсацию — комментариями. Засим прощаюсь. Имейте хоть каплю самоуважения: не пишите тому, кто пытается от вас отделаться.

Comment: Нет, на сайте отвечал меньше года. Сейчас почти только вы с Sharon отвечаете, поэтому так с баллами, а раньше была конкуренция гораздо больше, а отвечающие на один вопрос редко ставят друг другу лайки. Нет к вам зависти, только сочувствие. Не знаю, откуда в вас столько агрессии. Мои комментарии не для того, чтобы позлить и показать, что отвечающий тупой, а для того, чтобы ответ стал правильнее и лучше. Если бы хотел вас позлить, то вам бы была хана. Честно говоря, не хотелось с вами ругаться. Вы произвели хорошее впечатление изначально, а потом на вас что-то нашло, будто чёрт вселился.

Comment: @oleedd не переоценивайте себя. У меня нет стандартных болевых точек, чтобы какому-то ноунейму с форума удалось меня разозлить. Совет на будущее: изучите приёмы эристики, чтобы так легко на них не вестись.

Comment: Даже и не пытался вас разозлить. Чего ж вы настолько агрессивны стали? Разговаривали с вами очень культурно раньше. Никакой антипатии вы не вызывали. И насчёт баллов. Больше их ставят за элементарные, но не краткие ответы, в которых всё очевидно. Для себя решил на простые вопросы вообще не отвечать, а отвечать только на сложные. Такие не решаются просто ссылкой на правило. А за ответы на такие вопросы обычно много баллов не ставят (1-2), Sharon может подтвердить. И количество баллов показатель больше не ума, а времени, которое бесплатно уделяется сайту. То есть больше сидишь — больше баллов.

Comment: @oleedd надеюсь, что теперь я вызываю-таки антипатию и вы наконец отстанете.

Comment: Теперь вызываете, но чего вы так? Нельзя быть нормальным? Тем более что вас трудно разозлить (если это правда). Не хотелось вас в враги записывать. Когда активно отвечал (как вы сейчас), у меня прирост репутации был на первом месте, больше, чем у Sharon. И это при высокой конкуренции (сейчас её почти нет), тогда соревновались, кто первым ответит, кто-то мог ответить чуть раньше, и могло оказаться, что в ответе такое же, и получалось, что ответ написан зря (публиковать такое же нет смысла). Но потом понял, что это того не стоит. Так что баллы здесь ни при чём. Кроме вас, никто по ним не судит.

Comment: Раз вы так себя ведёте и не хотите быть нормальным, то не отстану, буду над вами издеваться. Или будьте культурным и нейтральным, как полагается.

Comment: @oleedd на сайтик пройдите.

Comment: И не собираюсь туда проходить, а вы пососите то, что на вашем сайтике.

Comment: Вот вы говорите про слово "суёшься". Так засуйте себе свою медальку и то, что на вашем сайтике.

Comment: @oleedd слабенько, весьма слабенько. Вы так себя позиционировали, как пря ммастера-раздражателя-издеватора, а на деле пшик, уровень второклассника.

Comment: Так я ещё не начинал. Всё-таки хочется дать вам шанс исправиться. Так пришлось опуститься до вашего уровня. Ссылочками он играется... Может, игрушку дать?